# MeasureString Ignores Font Styles for Arial and Times New Roman

Tags: c#, .net, string, system.drawing, measure

After completing the following code the value of "result1" and "result2" variables (measured width of string) are the same, despite the fact that the "font1" is regular and the "font2" is bold. Interestingly, this error appears for the font "Times New Roman" and "Arial". For example for font "Calibri" returned values ​​are correct, the value of the variable "result2" is greater than the value of the variable "result1". Why is this happening?

```
using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    graphics.PageUnit = System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    System.Drawing.Font font1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
    System.Drawing.Font font2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    float result1 = graphics.MeasureString("WWW", font1, int.MaxValue, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
    float result2 = graphics.MeasureString("WWW", font2, int.MaxValue, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they don't actually have the same width?  When typing "WWW" in Microsoft Word with Arial and Arial Bold, they appear to have the same width.

Comment: I've had issues with `MeasureString`. Instead I use the `TextRenderer` to measure the width of a string. Like so `Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Hi there!", new Font("Arial", 12.0F);)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it with different strings and the width does change. I think it just so happens that "WWW" has the same length with/without the bold style. Just try it in an editor and you'll see it's the same size.

Comment: Indeed, the returned values ​​are correct, the error was in the later calculations, my oversight, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Actually draw it in the OnPaint() method and you'll see why:

[image]